# Coded UI,how to change the testTimeout

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

For my project, want to increase the testTimeout.

While running my test, after 30 mins my test automatically stops.How to increase the testtimeout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestRunSummary</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <MSTest>
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>false</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>        
    </MSTest>
  <Execution>
    <Timeouts runTimeout="72000"/>
    </Execution>
</RunSettings>
```

Do i need to change anything on TestRun.runsettings

Comment: 1. Why do you have a CodedUI test that takes 30 mins :|?

Comment: the default test timeout for codedeui will be 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

Add the test settings file and change the timeout settings. [Specifying Test Settings for Visual Studio Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991.aspx)

Comment: thats the testsetting file i used,do i have to change anything on the file now. i have increased the timeout to 2hours.<Execution>
    <Timeouts testTimeout="72000"/>
    </Execution> .. No luck.nothing works

Comment: No the timeout settings in the test settings should work